# Search File by name using Search Everywhere from a specific folder: IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-17

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017 version and using **double shift (in MAC)** as a shortcut to search files from the entire project.

[image: Search Everywhere]

Question: I just want to restrict **Search everywhere** to a particular directory in my project (similar to find In path feature where we can specify InProject, Module, Directory, Scope as the parameter). Is it possible? If yes then how to do it.

[image: Find In Path]

Comment: That would no longer be "search everywhere" now would it? :P Isn't "Find in Path" exactly the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: @Zephyr Agreed on the first part *Search everywhere in Module* is more apt., On 2nd path **Search everywhere** tries to search file names, class names etc. ...whereas **Find In Path** specifically search for the content inside the file.

Comment: What are you trying to find?

Comment: It's possible to type part of folder name in search filed, e.g "fo/ba/Cl" to find all files containing "Cl" in name under "foo/bar" folder.